# Threaded Private Messages (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, messaging

I've found [simple-private-messages](https://github.com/professionalnerd/simple-private-messages), but I'm interested in a gem/plugin that includes message/conversation threading, or recommended approaches for modifying simple-private-messages to include that capability.

Comment: here is an approach: create trees using ancestry. Have a look here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry

Answer (score 0):

I know it's almost a year later, but you could try [has_messages_generators](https://github.com/fajrif/has_messages_generators). It creates threaded private messages with views.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's almost 2 years later, but [multi_recipient_threaded_messages](https://github.com/ychaker/multi_recipient_threaded_messages) is based on simple-private-messages and looks exactly what you wanted at that time. Salute.